# Migrating a classic ASP.NET MVC5 project which uses Ninject to Owin

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, ninject, owin

I have an ASP.NET MVC5 application which was created in the times of MVC3. During the times I've upgraded over and over until the current state which uses MVC5 and Ninject.

I use Ninject with the Nuget packages `Ninject.Web.Common` and `Ninject.MVC5`. To tell the truth I'm not even sure the latter is needed because MVC5 seems to use its built-in `IDependencyResolver` interface whenever it's needed.

The applicaion is run inside IIS, and all the setup and configuration is done in `Global.asax` file and `Web.config`.

Now we reached a point where we would like to use `SignalR` for a submodule, and so there is time to migrate the whole application to `Owin` as `SignalR` uses that too. I wouldn't like to make a mess with mixing several technologies.

I couldn't actually find any good guides about the required steps and what issues can occur, what with should take care of.

Has anybody done a similar migration?